# Preserve function property when created with "bind"

Tags: javascript, function, bind

I have a function that looks like this:

```
var tempFun = function() {
    return 'something';
}
tempFun.priority = 100;
```

Now I'm pushing it to an array and binding another object to it in the process like this:

```
var funArray = [];
var newObj = {};

funArray.push( tempFun.bind(newObj) );
```

and after this, I would like to acces the function's property like this:

```
funArray[0].priority
```

but it returns undefined. Is there some way to preserve the property on the function while binding a new object to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you could write a function to do this yourself;

```
Function.prototype.bindAndCopy = function () {
    var ret = this.bind.apply(this, arguments);

    for (var x in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
            ret[x] = this[x];
        }
    }

    return ret;
};
```

... which you could then use via;

```
var funArray = [];
var newObj = {};

funArray.push( tempFun.bindAndCopy(newObj) );
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Bind returns a new function, which "wraps" around the original one. All you can do is copy the properties on this new function:

```
var boundFun = tempFun.bind(newObj)
boundFun.priority = tempFun.priority;

funArray.push( boundFun );
```

If you want the properties to be in sync (changes in one visible on the other) you can do:

```
Object.defineProperty(boundFun, 'priority', {
  get : function () { return tempFun.priority; },
  set : function (val) { tempFun.priority = val; }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks very nice and might just be enough for my simple use case.

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Hence, `.bind()` won't be useful for what you're trying to achieve. Besides using jQuery mappers or rewriting your code to use `.prototype`, a solution that I can think of is:

```
var obj = {};
for (var i in tempFun) {
    if (tempFun.hasOwnProperty(i)) obj[i] = tempFun[i];
}
```